# Subjective / open-ended Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems to me that StackOverflow is designed to be a community which helps people be better programmers. It's really useful to be able to ask a specific question and get a specific answer. However, there is something to be said for increasing the scope of knowledge a person has as well -- introducing new concepts, new applications, etc. which might be related to a particular specific question.

The problem is that it's impossible for a person to ask a closed-ended question about something they don't know exists. It is also very hard to ask open-ended questions on SO because many people see them as overly broad. This effectively deprives stack overflow users of the ability to enhance their expertise beyond what they already know exists.

Arguably, a community's value is in knowledge-sharing. The value therefore could come from answering more open than closed questions, because closed questions can, by-and-large, be more readily answered through reading documentation.

I would love the ability to ask (1) a closed-ended question and invite (2) open-ended responses to a related question in a post, without being downvoted.

Eg. The following often attracts downvotes as being too broad:

> Q1: Does `object.method` return the method as an object?
>
> Q2: What are some applications of this?

The ability to include Q2 as a "bonus" question would be excellent as it would encourage deeper knowledge sharing. Right now, the community practice seems to be to confine these sorts of discussions to chat, which for obvious reasons may not be optimal.

**This question isn't about asking broader questions than SO allows, it's about asking for help on broader issues, but only those which are connected to specific tangible issues.**

Comment: It's unlikely to happen - encouraging open-ended responses is something that this community is not keen on, on the belief that it decreases overall  quality.

Comment: I get that, but at the same time, there's a lot of value that's being missed in terms of the ability to "discover" things that someone might not know. It's one thing to explain a concept, it's another to understand it's value and how to apply it to solve common programming problems.

Comment: I hear the quora website likes people to [wax poetic](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wax-poetic)

Comment: Good answers will naturally hit Q2 even if you don't explicitly ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand what you are saying. However, a lot of the verbose philosophy does not belong in succinct answers. IMO we need just enough to get the job done, nice formatting, and useful links.

And **short**, on-topic btw comments that dwell near the edges. Primarily for precautions and the like. If at all. Someone has to read that crap and I might be killing their brain cells. So those better be important.

We don't need Homerian Epics. x10 for all the Answers. Think of the poor chap that stumbles into that train wreck later looking for an answer.

Thankfully, stackoverflow provides for chat.stackoverflow.com

And I think people like to be told "geez, I really like your style of explaining that."

And on some occasions they might even like being asked "Can I ask 1 brief follow-up question, I promise just 1?"

And the receiver of that request might think "wow, someone likes my stuff, sure, I am game, I think".

That is chat. As in a chat room. Not chatty comments that pollute threads under Answers.

And those chat sessions are public if I recollect.

So many of us will within reason engage such conversations. Sparingly.

However, I would use this very infrequently, perhaps once a year, as a requester.

Just remember: "the next chap stumbling into your question" predicament. This Q&A format is meant to put a bow around it all as short and sweet as possible. Not cure insomnia, and degrade stackoverflow into quora.

Speaking of epics, this one ends now.

Comment: I like the answer, but I don't really agree. I think my disagreement stems from how you define "on topic." In the non-SO world, just because an answer doesn't have a finite answer doesn't make the response an 'epic,' 'chatty,' or a 'train wreck.' Also, questions without finite answers are exactly the same level of usefulness to the next person with the *same* question. It just so happens that when a question is open-ended, it is less likely, though not impossible, that the next chap will have the same question.

Comment: but it is a massive wild west in questions (in the tags). That requires some rules of engagement. I don't know what more to say. And I am not the one that defines "on topic". That is in the Help Pages. And interpretation of that is highly subjective, and varying from me to the next guy. That is what the Community is. This guy and that next guy. We try to find common ground on what is reasonable.

Comment: I get that. My point is more meta than the rules of the site, it's about the purposes of the site, and if the current rules are really doing the best job possible of fulfilling that purpose. Wikipedia, for example, does a pretty darn good job of taking open-ended information and stopping it from becoming a wild west. SO could probably handle implementing something similar if the spirit moved.

Comment: Anything that is information sharing and wiki-like sounds good. I wonder how that concept would work well on SO considering people arrive with their custom block of *stuff* and want an answers pronto tailored around their *unique* predicament.

Comment: I think my point is that SO could be more than that. I asked a similar question about the "wiki," only to find that it's not a wiki, it's just collaboratively edited questions. It would be great if high-level SO users had a chance to co-create a best-practices wiki, write a programming book together, whatever. I personally don't think SO is only about answering particular people's questions - it's about answering a particular question now, and "pre-answering" the same questions later. Sounds a lot like the function of a wikipedia-type-wiki to me.

Comment: The beauty of the Q/A format is that it gives folks a prompt to answer questions in detail. A lot of good answers do have the "more information" component baked-in, but it would be really cool to then collect that on a wiki.